# Invalid overload of 'islower'

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to develop the BattleShip game in C++ and I'm almost done. For that, I need my `gameOver` function working. My game is over when all the ships are sunk. Therefore, I'm trying to count how many lowercase chars I have in my string status (from Ship). When half of the chars are lowercase, the "ship" is destroyed and I'm ready to use my `gameOver` function.

But somehow my `count_if` isn't working and I don't know why.

Here you go:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool Ship::isDestroyed() const{ 
    //This counts those chars that satisfy islower:
    int lowercase = count_if (status.begin(), status.end(), islower); 
    return ( lowercase <= (status.length/2) ) ? true : false;
}

bool Board::gameOver() {
    bool is_the_game_over = true;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ships.size() ; i++){
        if( ships[i].isDestroyed() == false ) {
            //There is at least one ship that is not destroyed.
            is_the_game_over = false ;
            break;
        }
    }
    return is_the_game_over;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "Isn't working"?
Does it return 0, an unexpected value, half the expected value, MAX_INT, etc?

Comment: `ships[i].isDestroyed() == false` is more clearly written as `! ships[i].isDestroyed()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah! What about that `return` in `isDestroyed()`?

Comment: Shouldn't the `return` statement in `isDestroyed()` be `return ( lowercase >= (status.length/2) ) ? true : false;` ( `>=`, not `<=`)?

Comment: @RSahu Almost; it should be `return lowercase >= status.length/2;` (wink)

Comment: @DevSolar 'Sigh'... Come on, eyes, that's not funny...

Comment: @unwind: Yes, I missed that. `return ( lowercase <= (status.length/2) ) ? true : false;` is more clearly written as `return lowercase <= (status.length/2);` (assuming that's the correct condition).

Comment: The condition is: if (lowercase >= (status.length())/2) return true; else return false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the algorithm call the following way

```
int lowercase = count_if (status.begin(), status.end(), ::islower); 
                                                        ^^^
```

The compilers are allowed to place standard C functions in the global namespace.

Otherwise use a lambda expression as for example

```
int lowercase = count_if (status.begin(), status.end(), 
                          []( char c ) return islower( c ); } );
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much. The gameOver function isn't working though but I guess I need a new topic for that.

Comment: @Perseverance Maybe you mean  return status.length / 2 < lowercase; instead of return ( lowercase >= (status.length/2) ) ? true : false; That is that lower case letters is greater than the half of the string.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, the standard library has more than one overload of `islower` (a function from the C library, and a function template from the localisation library), so you can't simply name the function unless you're calling it.

You could convert it to the right function type:

```
static_cast<int (*)(int)>(islower)
```

or hope that your implementation dumps the C library into the global namespace as well as `std`:

```
::islower      // not guaranteed to work
```

or wrap it in a lambda

```
[](int c){return islower(c);}
```